# Spring classNotFound when creating spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

### When I creating bean with name userSevice, I got classNotFound Exception. I'm using spring web-mvc and spring-security

This my bean in servlet.xml

```
<bean id="userService" class="tr.com.xxx.service.UserService"></bean>
```

---

This class which I want to create it's bean

```
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@PostConstruct  
protected void initialize() {
    //accountRepository.save(new Account("user", "demo", "ROLE_USER"));
    //accountRepository.save(new Account("admin", "admin", "ROLE_ADMIN"));
    System.out.print("inside aouth");
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.print("inside loadByUserName");
    Account account = accountRepository.findByEmail(username);
    if(account == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");
    }
    return createUser(account);
}

public void signin(Account account) {
    System.out.print("sign in");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate(account));
}

private Authentication authenticate(Account account) {
    System.out.print("inside authenticate");
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(createUser(account), null, account.getAuthorities());
}

private User createUser(Account account) {
    System.out.print("inside cu");
    return new User(account);
}

private static class User extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    private final Account account;

    public User(Account account) {
        super(account.getEmail(), account.getPassword(), account.getAuthorities());
        this.account = account;
        System.out.print("inside user");
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return getAccount().isAdmin();
    }
}

}
```

---

And my error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tr.com.xxx.service.UserService
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
... 18 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the package is the correct one?

Comment: did you configure servlet.xml as your spring resource file

Comment: I can go using ctrl + click in eclipse so I'm sure

Comment: @naman how can I do this

Comment: Is it web application?

Comment: Have you configured Spring dispatcher servlet in web.xml?

Comment: yes like that <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: Can you add `<context:annotation-config />` in servlet.xml.

Comment: Ok I added but still continue same problem.

Comment: Is it coming on server startup?

Comment: Yes when I start server

Comment: Is any other bean getting created?

Comment: No actually I am using a tutorial code which create beans inside code not xml. I am trying to convert that to xml based bean.

Comment: Is there maven dependencies?

Comment: Yes there are maven dependencies.

Comment: I am not sure but many a times I have seen that we need to right click on project> properties> Deployment Assembly> Add maven dependencies... and run project after building again

Comment: Can you show us your `servlet.xml` and `web.xml`.

Comment: Anyway, how can I load my conf class when servlet startup. Its my conf class @Configuration
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:spring-security-context.xml")
class SecurityConfig {}

Comment: If you want to load spring-security-context.xml then you can provide it in web.xml in context-param. Need to see your web.xml, servlet.xml and spring-security-context.xml